# TextField not show bottom line when value is empty string Material Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cosmicmind

I'm using `material textfield` in a view. But when this `textfield's` value is empty string the underline is not be shown. How can I fix it?

In the below image: `email2` has empty `string` and the underline is not be shown.

[image]

Here is my view:

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit
import Material

class EditMailView: UIView {

    public let email1: UILabel = {
        let lb = UILabel()
        lb.text = "email1"
        lb.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        return lb
    }()

    public let email2: UILabel = {
        let lb = UILabel()
        lb.text = "email2"
        lb.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        return lb
    }()

    public let email1Input: TextField = {
        let field = TextField()
        field.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        return field
    }()

    public let email2Input: TextField = {
        let field = TextField()
        field.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        return field
    }()


    public let email1Counter: UILabel = {
        let lb = UILabel()
        lb.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        return lb
    }()

    public let email2Counter: UILabel = {
        let lb = UILabel()
        lb.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        return lb
    }()


    convenience init(email1 e1: String, email2 e2: String) {
        self.init(frame: .zero)

        email1Input.text = e1
        email2Input.text = e2

        addSubview(email1)
        addSubview(email2)
        addSubview(email1Input)
        addSubview(email2Input)
        addSubview(email1Counter)
        addSubview(email2Counter)

        email1.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(10)
            make.left.equalTo(10)
            make.right.equalTo(10)
            make.bottom.equalTo(email1Input.snp.top).offset(-10)
        }

        email1Input.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(email1.snp.bottom).offset(10)
            make.left.equalTo(10)
            make.right.equalTo(10)
            make.bottom.equalTo(email1Counter.snp.top).offset(-10)
        }

        email1Counter.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(email1Input.snp.bottom).offset(10)
            make.left.equalTo(10)
            make.right.equalTo(10)
            make.bottom.equalTo(email2.snp.top).offset(-10)
        }

        email2.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(email1Counter.snp.bottom).offset(10)
            make.left.equalTo(10)
            make.right.equalTo(10)
            make.bottom.equalTo(email2Input.snp.top).offset(-10)
        }

        email2Input.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(email2.snp.bottom).offset(10)
            make.left.equalTo(10)
            make.right.equalTo(10)
            make.bottom.equalTo(email2Counter.snp.top).offset(-10)
        }

        email2Counter.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(email2Input.snp.bottom).offset(10)
            make.left.equalTo(10)
            make.right.equalTo(10)
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-10)
        }
    }
}
```

And Controller:

```
import UIKit
import Snapkit

class EditMailController: UIViewController {

    let editView = EditMailView(email1: "123@abc.xyz", email2: "")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        view.addSubview(editView)

        editView.snp.makeConstraints { (maker) in
            maker.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }

        editView.email1.becomeFirstResponder()

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: @iPatel will update question.

Comment: @iPatel I updated my question. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has resolved. Instead try to set value for email2 with empty string like:

```
email1Input.text = e1
email2Input.text = e2
```

I ignored when e2 is empty string like this:

```
email1Input.text = e1
if !e2.isEmpty {
    email2Input.text = e2
}
```